# What does “addressing” mean in the below context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> It also represents a symbolic end to Russia's often tortured process of ***addressing*** the repressions of the Soviet era.

What does “***adressing***” mean here? I’ve looked it up  in several dictionaries, and cannot decide which one actually fits the context here.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *to address* as used in your example has the meaning of *to begin to deal with an issue or problem* (see meaning #4 along with examples in [**the Macmillan English Dictionary**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/address_2)). To make the point clearer, let's rewrite your sentence substituting *addressing* with the meaning that I just described:

> It also represents a symbolic end to Russia's often tortured process of **beginning to deal with the problem of** the repressions of the Soviet era.

Comment: Michael, nice answer! +1

Comment: Thanks, it’s so kind of you to give such a complete answer! I actually cannot wait to accept your perfect answer, but the system wouldn’t let me and told me I can do it in 1 minute. : )